# MySQL case-sensitivity for column names

Tags: mysql, sql, database, innodb, case-sensitive

I want to have `case-sensitive` column names in `MySQL` (I am using `InnoDB` storage engine).

```sql
-- Below raises an error. 
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `name` varchar(255),
    `NAME` varchar(255)
)
```

Is it possible to achieve it ?

Thanks !

Comment: I will check it.

Thanks for help !